# Автокомплит, как у wikimart

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Хочу сделать JQuery Autocomplete с категориями, например, как тут: [wikimart](wikimart.ru).
Документация: [ui Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories).

В документации не могу понять, как сделать с категориями при использовании удаленного файла?
Там в примере - локальный источник.
А мне надо, чтоб сервер отдавал информацию.

Вообще, в идеале хочу, как у wikimart. Посоветуйте, что использовать.

Comment: @armenka, не забывайте принимать верные ответы. Для этого нужно кликнуть на галочку рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код дополнятеля с категориями

```
<script>
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

А в настройках дописать

```
source: "search.php"
```

Только вот search.php должен возвратить что-то наподобие массива

```
    var data = [
        { label: "anders", category: "" },
        { label: "andreas", category: "" },
        { label: "antal", category: "" },
        { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
        { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
        { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
        { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
        { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
    ];
```

Comment: Это всё на основе
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories
и
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote